# How to get the params of an included controller-action to use them in the caller-parent view

Tags: jquery, grails

I want to hide a div if a list is empty. The reason is DRY and not to call the database twice.

It would be the controller code, where the variable `testInstanceTotal` is created:

```
class TestController {
    def user = getAuthenticatedUser()
    def userStuff = Alojamiento.findAllByUser(user)     
    [testInstanceList: userStuff, testInstanceTotal: userStuff.size()]
}
```

It would be the code of the caller-parent view:

```
<div id="divShowOrHide">                                        
    <g:include controller="test" action="list" />

    <g:if test="${testInstanceTotal == 0}">
        $('#divShowOrHide').hide();                 
    </g:if>                             
</div>
```

To check what is it going on. I added the next code:

```
<%=testInstanceTotal %>
<%=params %>
```

This is displayed at the browser (note: the caller-parent view is the index.gsp):

```
 [id:null]
```

So no params of the included controller-action are available from the caller-parent view. How could I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of writing java script code on index.gsp, you should write js code on the list GSP page, because that will have response variables.

As you are using include list, you may have a list page, which will render at that place, if you add your JS code, which will hide parent div then it will work.

for example on the index.gsp:

```
    <div id="divShowOrHide">                                        
    <g:include controller="test" action="list" />

</div>
```

and on the list.gsp, (the page which will render your controller's action):

```
<script>
<g:if test="${testInstanceTotal == 0}">
        $('#divShowOrHide').hide();                 
    </g:if>                             
</script>
```

then you will not need to access response on the request page, and your div will be hidden.
hope this will help.